# Precise, concise edge length measurement using a decimal point

Tags: measurement

I switched on edge length measurements. For a length of e.g. 1.054 I get a value "1m 5cm". It lacks precision, takes place and is hard to read. Any way of getting a precise value with a decimal point and preferably no unit lengths at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can change your units here:

[image]

if you set Unit System to none you will get this:

[image]